# How can I get a cell's value in gridview in OnRowDataBound?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I've got a gridview containing several rows. What I'm trying to do is basically to get a specific value of a string in the gridview, every time a row is changed(With OnRowDataBound).

I've tried quite a lot options, and yes, I did google it, but I couldn't find a solution that fits my need. I'd appreciate it if you could help me out with it.

My current code(Which doesn't work, **error message:** *Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index*):

```
protected void ViewJobs_DataBind(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.RowIndex);
        string replymessage = ViewJobs.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(replymessage))
            IfReply = true;
    }
}
```

***Html:***

```
    <% if (IfReply == true) { %>
        <span style=" font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;"> Reply To: <%# Eval("Reply") %>  | By: <%# Eval("Sender") %> </span>
        <% IfReply = false;
    } %>
```

It is basically done to show the span above if *replymessage* is not null in the current row in the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

**If by Changing row means "on selecting any row", you can use selected index changed event everytime a row is clicked.**

**aspx page:-**

```
<asp:gridview id="ViewJobs"  runat="server"      
onselectedindexchanged="ViewJobs_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

**Code Behind :-**

```
void ViewJobs_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = ViewJobs.SelectedRow;
   string replymessage = row.Cells[1].Text;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(replymessage))
        IfReply = true;
}
```